# OOP object models, best practice

Tags: php, oop

I have a very specific issue in mind, regarding on how to implement data models using instantiable classes. For example, let's say I have a list of cars in my database, and somewhere in my code I will have both the need to load a specific car, and to load all of the cars.

Does it make more sense to create a class `Cars` where `$cars = new Cars;` would return all cars, and when I need a specific car, I would call a static method `Cars::getCar($id)`?

Or vice-versa, have a class `Car` where `$car = new Car($id)` would return a specific car, and when I need all of them, I would call a static method `Car::getAll()`?

In both these cases, these static methods would in this case return simple arrays?

Would it make more sense (but it seems very impractical) to have both an instantiable class `Car` and an instantiable class `Cars`?

Is there yet another, ultimately better way?

Comment: First case makes the most sense for me

Comment: Some people implement custom collection types like you would have `Cars` do, but I dislike this. I would suggest naming it `CarDealership` (or whatever is appropriate in your scenario) and have that hold a collection of `Car` objects as a member of the class. Now you can have `getCar($id)` and `getAllCars()` as a method on this class.

Comment: On the background this should be only one class per one entity - `Car`. If you need all cars, then create a array (collection) of `Car` instances. A wrapper around it could provide you interfaces to that collection with `getAll()` method.

Comment: You should have a `Car` class which represents *one* car, and a `CarStorage` or `CarRepository` or something along those lines which contains the code to get cars in and out of the database. That in aggregate is *the model*, "models" is not a real thing. None of this should be static methods. See the duplicate.

Comment: @RoyalBg When you say collection of Car instances, can you be more specific as to how I would achieve this in code? To have their instances, I would have to invoke the constructor on each returned row?